# When do I punch the ball in Lucioball?

Tags: overwatch

I don't know when to punch the ball. Sometimes when I hit the ball, it goes far, other times it's like I just poked it...

When should I hit the ball to get the best results?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods:

1 - **Normal punch**, left mouse button. This is the normal punch and the strength is low. This type is good to go to run behind the ball and make the high punch when you are near the goal. You can punch the ball with more energy if before to punch it you use <kbd>e</kbd>.

2 - **High punch**, right mouse button. This is the power punch and the strength is very high. It's necessary to take away the ball from your goal or to make a goal.

And then in pitch there are on the floor some yellow zones, in this areas lucio can make a mega jump. I don´t test if in this area the normal punch could be more powerful, but if you can jump the double could be sense to make double "damage" to the ball.

Comment: Note that the right click has a cool down.

Comment: What action is bound to 'e'? Overwatch is also played on consoles, and people may re-bind their buttons even on PC.

Comment: e makes you can go faster. On consoles I don´t know what buttom is.

Comment: @DCShannon More accurately it's the binding for *Amp it Up!*

Comment: re: hitting E to punch with more energy.. I had no idea, thanks for the tip. Additionally, I thought the 2nd method was only for players. I wish they communicated this to players better.